# Registering 0.5 of a participant! Should this be possible?

Tags: civievent, price-sets, fields

I was surprised to find, while testing the 'Minimum Amount' setting for a Price Set, that you could put eg 0.1, or 3.14159, in to the Text/Numeric Quantity field.

This seemed wrong but I assume that overcoming this correctly would mean that Price Set should have another Field option of Integer.

Any thoughts?